# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever i build my project in android studio it gives me the following error
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
below is my build.gradle file
lastly the line that has implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0' also gives an  error saying...
 All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.iwatchug"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

repositories {
    google()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
```

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> Note: Don't use the combined `play-services` target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

You need to add specific google play services library, example:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
```